# Android Best approach - performance perspective

Tags: android, performance, view, processor

I was looking for an official documentation telling this; 
Which is the best approach to use :

1. Using image(.png/.jpg) as background for Views
2. Using xml/color for background

I have heard from lot of people, that rendering images are more expensive(processor)than using xml or any kind of 'non-image' methods to display in view.
What do you think about this? Is this a myth or is it real ?

I want to create an android app that has lot of Button and other UI components that have gloss effects up and down. I would like to convince my client to avoid using images and use 'non-image' components so as to improve app efficiency. But for this I need a solid document or some proof to make him believe this.

Thanks in adavance

Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

It will totally depend on the platform and the image.

The complexity of the image and the size you wish to show it at will affect the cost of loading and appropriately scaling the image.

Vector images (which is what I assume you mean by "xml") may be more appropriate depending on the platform, image and scaling.

There can be no definitive answer to your question.

Comment: thanks @Matt Lacey for the reply. My doubt is about the major platforms like Android/IOS. How would you like to implement some view with a solid color as background ? and why?

Comment: If that's what you want to know I'd advise asking a specific question for each platform. This generic question can't be answered and will likely soon be closed.

Comment: ok, done Now I had made it just for Android